# Django - Trying to access numbers in for loop via counter

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm building a site which there's comments and stuff. And I want to users to see a icon for their comments and that should toggle two more buttons which are edit and delete. In order to do this I have to give different ids for each div that I want to be toggled.

Basically what I want to do:

```
1st iteration -- access to numbers 1 and 2
2nd iteration -- access to numbers 3 and 4
3rd iteration -- access to numbers 5 and 6
```

The code has to look like this:

```html
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse"
                aria-expanded="false" 
                aria-controls="multiCollapseComment1 multiCollapseComment2">
            <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseComment1">
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1"
                       href="#">Edit</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseComment2">
                    <a class=" btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" 
                       href="#">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse"
                aria-expanded="false" 
                aria-controls="multiCollapseComment3 multiCollapseComment4">
            <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseComment3">
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1"
                       href="#">Edit</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseComment4">
                    <a class=" btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" 
                       href="#">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to access those numbers via `{{forloop.counter|add:"1"}}` but it's not the solution.  Because I realized that even if I add 1 viait won't work because it's going to be something like this: 1,2 ; 2,3; .... but i need 1,2; 3,4; 5,6 for each loop. How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31344351/2036767

Comment: @DiegoPuente Sorry but can you take a look at question again please?

Comment: why don't use a combination to create a key? like `multiCollapseComment{{object.pk}}edit{{comment.pk}}` and `multiCollapseComment{{object.pk}}delete{{comment.pk}}`

Comment: It's like I'm looping over only comments so there's not gonna be any changes in `{{object.pk}}` since this is a template for detail view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i supposed two things:

1. you are in a loop.
2. in the example there are two comments.

so if you are in a loop, with just one of them will work.

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse"
                aria-expanded="false" 
                aria-controls="multiCollapseComment{{comment.id}}edit multiCollapseComment{{comment.id}}delete">
    <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
</button>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseComment{{comment.id}}edit">
            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1"
                href="#">Edit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseComment{{comment.id}}delete">
            <a class=" btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" 
                href="#">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<-- i supposed that this is another comment -->

<button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse"
                aria-expanded="false" 
                aria-controls="multiCollapseComment{{comment.id}}edit multiCollapseComment{{comment.id}}delete">
    <i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
</button>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseComment{{comment.id}}edit">
            <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1"
                href="#">Edit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseComment{{comment.edit}}delete">
            <a class=" btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" 
                href="#">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah yes that should work, I didn't think of adding letters instead of numbers(what a noob), thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with a **built-in filter** by name **"add"**

You can use it to **add a number**

Example:

```
  {{ forloop.counter|add:"1" }}
```

For More detail checkout the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference)

Comment: Sorry but I won't help. I just made a silly thought. Can you look at the question again please?

Comment: do you want to skip the +1 part if the forloop.counter gets even number?

Comment: yes, but it's like
1st iteration `multiCollapseComment1 multiCollapseComment2` 

2nd one `multiCollapseComment3 multiCollapseComment4`